# Using Relativelayout in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I've known `ConstraintLayout` can makes more flexible view than `RelativeLayout`.
and using `ConstraintSet` can make child view of `ConstraintLayout` transformed.

Is it a proper way to use `RelativeLayout` in `ConstraintLayout` in my case below?

I'd like to click `RelativeLayout(ViewGroup)` to enter another activity.
and I've tried to use `barrier` and `group` using `ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 2` but these can't be used for view group click event.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- other views-->

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="400dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <!-- Bottom view-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Brief"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have already used RelativeLayout using 'onClickListener'.
What I want to know is "Is it right way to use RelativeLayout in ConstraintLayout?".

Comment: It's not the right way. ConstraintLayout came to prevent the usage of nested layouts. Remove the relative layout and put a view on top(zindex) of your clickable zone. Set the click listener to that view and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use constraintlayout and at the same time use a card-like UI. You should enclose a constraintlayout inside a cardview.  Implement the cardview onClick() and align views accordingly inside contraintlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!-- Your views aligned below -->
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```